# GUI is blurred after yum update in fedora 15

Tags: fedora, display

Since last few days I was using fedora 15 without any issue. But after updating fedora 15 using yum update command.

Here is the screen shot

[image]

How to fix this issue, is there any missing package ?

Comment: Have you tried checking if the output od `dmesg`, or `cat /var/log/syslog` show errors regarding `display` or `xserver`?

Comment: Also, tell us what video hardware you have, and what drivers you use for it (e.g. Nvidia vs. nouveau).

Comment: ...and why Fedora 15, since it's EOL since a while now?

Comment: @schaiba here is the output of `lspci | grep VGA` command 
 `00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Ivy Bridge Graphics Controller (rev 09)`

Comment: @Alan i didn't able find logs with this location

Comment: Ivy Bridge and the subsequent integrated video chipset were released about a year ago. Fedora 15 is EOL since about a year and a half ago, if memory serves. So upgrade. :)

Comment: so it means i need to upgrade my video hardware ?? @schaiba

Comment: No, it means you need to upgrade Fedora from 15 to a supported version (17 or 18 at this time).

Comment: is there any other way to fix this ?? because before yum update it was working fine @schaiba

Comment: Fedora 15 has been discontinued some 6 months ago, Fedora 16 has recently been discontinued. Upgrade to Fedora 18 (17 has just a few months left). Or migrate to the rather similar [CentOS](http://www.centos.org) if frequent upgrading is a chore.

Comment: @vonbrand but my question is why it was working fine before `yum update` ?

Comment: It is hard to tell. Perhaps some botched update (and as it is EOL, there won't be any fixes). You can go looking through `/var/log/yum.log` looking for updates before the breakage, and revert them (if the packages are still to be found). Might go though Bugzilla and see if something like this is reported. Check if a LiveCD for a new version does the same (possible hardware breakage?).